# Strange iOS app store update/install behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store

I've recently released a significant update to an iOS application, lets call the new version 2.0 and the previously uploaded 1.0. The v2.0 update became ready for sale and was released to the store on September 20, 2012 09:35 (~6 days ago). Since then I've been seeing some extremely strange behaviour when a user updates or installs my app for the first time. Several users (and myself) have downloaded the update only to see the previously uploaded v1.0 binary installed even though the app store meta data accurately reflects the new version. Uninstalling the app and re-downloading it then results in the correct v2.0 app being installed. This behaviour has been seen as recently as 12 hours ago. I'm also seeing several users complaining about crashes in the update which I'm positive only arise in the old version. Is it somehow possible that I've caused this issue to arise through project settings? I'm thinking not but I'd really like to get to the bottom of this as it's negatively impacting the apps ratings.

Comment: Stored data (even data in `NSUserDefaults`) in previous versions of your app will remain after update. Maybe that's why all of your problems happening. Path to the main bundle of the app is changed when user updates the app (For cases if you saved some resource's path somewhere in old version of the app).

Comment: Hi Fahri, I've seen this behaviour both on a fresh install of the app and on an update. I assume stored data doesn't persist if an app is uninstalled?

Comment: If you are using keychain to store the data, that will remain, other data will be erased. Sorry for late reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved my problem.

- In itunes connect click on the app icon.
- Select 'Rights and Pricing'
- Select 'Manage iCloud settings for this app'
- Now check the versions that you don't want the users to download from iCloud.